# Facebook graphapi claim pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to request access to a page with my business manager running this call in graphapi:
POST: `{businessid}/client_pages?page_id={pageid}&permitted_roles=['ADVERTISER']`

With my systemuser admin token as requested per documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-asset-management/guides/pages

this will result in an error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "{traceid}"
  }
}
```

Now i cant find anywhere in the documentation that i need further permissions than just being a systemuser and having access to the business.

My permission list on developer.facebook
[image]

I am missing a permission but i cant figure out which one, any ideas ? :)

Cheers